# D3 Tree add and remove nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, css, d3.js

I am using D3.js to create a Dynamic Tree Chart, it starts with one node and then you can add/remove nodes as you want. You can also edit the node text to match your criteria.

So adding nodes it's working perfectly with the exception that it doesn't draw links far from depth 1... Which is annoying because I can't find the reason, I've tried everything I imagined.

Also, I can't remove a node, also tried everything I knew, searched almost everywhere but couldn't find some sample code to work on...

This is my tree

[image: D3 Tree]

As you can see, links are only working for Depth 1. Also, it has a red button (REMOVE NODE) and a green button (ADD NODE)

I am really upset because I've been working on this two things which aren't working for 6 or 7 hours... I think I'm going to throw it and use simple input boxes with some CSS3 tricks, but isn't cool...

I've created a `fiddle` with my full code for this, I hope you can help me out.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wt8cd6hh/
```

Comment: To make appending nodes work properly, you need to handle the enter selection for the links as well in your code. At the moment, you're only doing this for the nodes.

Comment: But how do I do that with the new nodes? And also to remove them? Could yo please write some code in order to guide me? I am pretty new to D3 actually

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes i've seent hat tutorial, but I can't see how to manage to add/remove new nodes directly from the tree. As I said I'm pretty new to D3 and some concepts are out of my range, even looking at some tutorials I'd not seen any kind of code like the one I am trying to write. Not even a simple example.

Comment: You didn't update the `nodes` array you're using to get your links -- http://jsfiddle.net/wt8cd6hh/1/